# How to convert nested numpy arrays in a dictionary to JSON?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I'm parsing nested dictionaries, which have different degrees of how nested they are (dictionaries within dictionaries within dictionaries, etc.) I do not know beforehand to what degree the dictionaries are nested.

The problem is, certain dictionary values are `numpy.ndarrays`. When I try to write the dictionary `my_dictionary` to JSON with

```
with open(my_dictionary, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_dictionary, f, indent=4)
```

I will get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable
```

Naturally, one way to overcome this would be to simply convert all `numpy.ndarray` values into a list with `.tolist()`.

However, given I do not know how nested the dictionaries are, how could I algorithmically check all values of any nested dictionary and convert `ndarray` to list?

Or is there another way to overcome this error?

Comment: May be change the title? something like "nested dict of ndarrays to json..."

Comment: @DanielKonstantinov I tried to edit above. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make custom `json.JSONEncoder`. For example:

```
import json


class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)


data = {"data": [{"obj": np.array([1, 2, 3])}]}

print(json.dumps(data, cls=MyEncoder, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "obj": [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```